# How to make a list of one item just that item

Tags: python, list

Let's say I have a list of strings

`s = ['boy', 'girl', 'toy']`

...but know at some point in my code the list will only contain one element

`s = ['boy']`

Is there an elegant way to make s = 'boy' and take it out of the list format?

I have been using a for loop like this..

```
for element in s:
    remaining_s = element
```

But I think it's inefficient. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> at some point in my code the list will only contain one element

Then that's super easy

```
s = your_lst[0]
```